# XLink & XPointer in real world app

Tags: .net, xbrl, xlink, xpointer

1. Do you know some real examples of implementation and real use of **extended** XLink and XPointer?
2. Does extended XLink or XPointer have some data model - can it be somehow a part of the DOM?
3. Are there some standard approaches (libraries) how to process **extended** XLink on .NET (Visual Basic)?
4. I'm interested in XBRL whose concept partly stands on the use of extended XLink (linkbases), but I have a doubts whether the XBRL could be succesfull in practice in its whole complexity (if government does not declare it as an obligatory accounting format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 [Docbook](http://docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/extendedlink.html) uses **extended** XLink

2 [XLink DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/#sample-dtd-appx) includes the **extended** element and attribute, so they are accessible using XPath.

3 [XPath API](http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-xml_vb.html) should be able to process the **extended** XLink nodes

4 [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169058) and [Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-brix-project/id381245805) platforms have XBRL tools, and [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-think43/) has best practices

**References**

- [Docbook Release Notes](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.78.0/RELEASE-NOTES.html)
- [Accelerating XBRL Adoption (pdf)](https://www.adobe.com/financial/pdfs/xbrl_wp.pdf)